# PowerPoint: Find in Files

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, find-in-files

I'm looking for the ability to "Find in Files" for PowerPoint 2003. I've searched Google but couldn't find anything.

Does such a feature exist? If not, is there an easy way to find keywords in a group of PowerPoint presentation files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Search has a function of searching text inside files, that, as far as I remember, works ok for MS Office files.

Comment: Even in Windows XP?

Comment: Yes in advanced search options. Should work for ppts.